# App keeps crashing at start, after implementing firebase

Tags: android, firebase

We tried to implement a Firebase database into our project, but it crashes directly at the start. Another problem is that we are not that good with databases but I hope that we can fix the problem.

Here is the exception which occurs at the start

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest, PID: 19187
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest-N3UsgThAADh1hlowT55AfA==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:66)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:55)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:155)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:553)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:300)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:264)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:249)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
```

Here is our database class for downloading and viewing our data

```
   package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.R;
    import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.recipe;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ViewDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "ViewDatabase";

        //add Firebase Database stuff
        private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
        private DatabaseReference myRef;
        private String recipes;

        private ListView listView_test;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_database_layout);


            //declare the database reference object. This is what we use to access the database.
            //NOTE: Unless you are signed in, this will not be useable.
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("testrecipe");
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            recipes = user.getUid();



            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    showData(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }


        private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                recipe recipe = new recipe();
                recipe.setNameOfRecipe(ds.child(recipes).getValue(com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.recipe.class).getNameOfRecipe());



                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
                array.add(recipe.getNameOfRecipe());
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.shopping_list_item, array);
                listView_test.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mAuthListener != null) {
                mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
            }
        }


        /**
         * customizable toast
         * @param message
         */
        private void toastMessage(String message){
            Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and the fragment where we want to show the information with a button click

```
package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.AHome;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.MainActivity;
import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.R;
import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ViewDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private Button categorie1;
    private Button categorie2;
    private Button categorie3;
    private Button categorie4;
    private Button database_button;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( HomeViewModel.class );

        View root = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_home, container, false );
        categorie1 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_category_1);
        categorie2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_category_2);
        categorie3 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_category_3);
        categorie4 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_category_4);
        database_button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_database);
        initButtons();

        final TextView textView = root.findViewById( R.id.text_home );
        homeViewModel.getText().observe( this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText( s );
            }
        } );
        return root;
    }

    public void initButtons(){
        categorie1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        categorie2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        categorie3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        categorie4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        database_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewDatabase.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After fixing the first one, we got a new one when we click the button at the home fragment

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest, PID: 20309
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest/com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ViewDatabase}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ViewDatabase.onCreate(ViewDatabase.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20309 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: share your build.gradle

Comment: Can you post your **build.gradle** file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're missing Firebase Auth library, so try adding

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
```

in your `app/build.gradle`.

I faced the same error before and adding Firebase Auth fixed it for me. I read somewhere that if you're using Firestore in your app, then you need to add Firebase Authentication library too.

Comment: Well, maybe giving the reason for downvoting would be appreciated. I'm pretty sure adding Firebase auth fixed the error for me.

Comment: We it;s better to put a comment before downvote . Maybe your problem is you can't suggest without knowing the build.gradle file . Right?

Comment: @MuntasirAonik Yeah but I'm pretty sure adding Firebase auth fixed it for me. So why waste time? If it doesn't work, I'll simply delete the answer.

Comment: There might be other issues right ? mixing up version's also give this error.

Comment: @TimonDoo don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. It's the checkmark sign between upvote and downvote buttons near the answer.

Comment: @MuntasirAonik it fixed the issue. Read the comment on the answer. It's not wrong to write the answers that worked for you. It it doesn't work for one person, I'm sure some other person will find it helpful. Remember it's not only 1 person that'll face this error, there'll be other people too.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise firebase first

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```